# .slideDown or .animate({ to a image above background image but before markup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

So, I have a div with text content, and a background property.

sample mark-up:

`<div id="largeicedcoffee">Yada Yada, text content, Lorem Ipsum, Sally likes Joe, Joe Hates Sally, doesn't really matter because Sally is a... text content</div>`

sample css:

```
#largeicedcoffee { 
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    background: url('..images/greytexture.jpg");
}
```

**What I'm trying to do:**

I would like a triangle to '**layer**' in **above** the background *image*, but **behind** the *text*. It will have an opacity of `.5;` *(no I don't want to just put it over the text as the text will be effected)*

[image]

The effect I want is the triangle to come in from top to left (to look like it's drawing into place from start point of highest point of triangle).. *and then downward.*

Now, I know with jQuery and CSS3 you can do this with `.slideDown or .animate({`  or with CSS3 something like: `transition: top 300ms cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.94);` on a regular element or foreground element.

But, any thought's on achieving this with the layer aspect as described background image > draw triangle > regular mark-up.

**Is there a better / more stable way then just having 3 elements `position: absolute;` and toggling a `z-index:` across; is that the only way?**

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the whole idea, but questions sounding like "Can I do this another way" or "Is there a better way" should be asked on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) IMO

Comment: Well, not really; because the layering with position absolute and zindex is a bad practice and pretty much a hack. Wondering if there is a 'legit' way to do this. And I'm fairly certain it can be done with JS.

Comment: Yet it works... I would probably use canvas to make it cleaner in that case